# Что будет, если не указать stage в job'e gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner, yml

Написал раннер и сделал через extends сборку для разных окружений: dev, prod сделал job'ы специально под переменные, дабы не надо было устраивать капипаст

Что у меня получилось:

```
stages:
  - prepare
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
  - activate
  - revert


before_script:
  - echo "--------- STARTING WORK ------------"


variables:
  docker_html_path: "/var/www"
  ENV: "dev"
#  CI_DEBUG_SERVICES: "true"


prepare-composer:
  image: composer:latest
  stage: prepare
  script:
    - mkdir -p storage/framework/cache storage/framework/sessions storage/framework/testing storage/framework/views tests/js/screens/diffs/ vendor/ tests/js/screenshots tests/js/report/
    - composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
    - composer install --no-interaction --prefer-source --ignore-platform-reqs
    - ls -lha
  artifacts:
    when: always
    name: $ENV_$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    untracked: true
    paths:
      - tests/js/screenshots/
      - tests/js/screens/
      - tests/js/report/
  cache:
    untracked: true
    when: always
    paths:
      - tests/js/screenshots/
      - tests/js/screens/
      - tests/js/report/
      - storage/
      - public
      - css/
      - img/
  tags:
    - test_new_runner
  only:
    - ned_runner #Затычка бранча чтобы ранер не запускался


build:
  image: node:14.15.0-stretch
  script:
    - npm i
    - npm run prod
    - ls -lha
  artifacts:
    when: always
    name: $ENV_$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    untracked: true
    paths:
      - tests/js/screenshots/
      - tests/js/screens/
      - tests/js/report/
  cache:
    paths:
      - tests/js/screenshots/
      - tests/js/screens/
      - tests/js/report/
      - storage/
  tags:
    - test_new_runner
  only:
    - ned_runner #Затычка бранча чтобы ранер не запускался
#    - develop


build-master:
  extends: build
  stage: build
  variables:
    ENV: prod
  tags:
    - test_new_runner
  only:
    - main


build-dev:
  extends: build
  stage: build
  variables:
    ENV: dev
  only:
#    - develop
    - ned_runner

test:
  variables:
    allow_failure: "true"
  image: miekrif/uzavr-selenium:latest
  services:
    - name: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
      alias: chrome
  script:
    - npx mocha tests/js/screenshots-* --timeout 50000
    - npx playwright test tests/js/pw_*
    - php artisan test
    - ls -lha
  artifacts:
    when: always
    name: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
    untracked: true
    paths:
      - tests/js/screenshots/
      - tests/js/screens/
      - tests/js/report/
  cache:
    paths:
      - tests/js/screenshots/
      - tests/js/screens/
      - tests/js/report/
      - storage/
      - public
      - css/
      - img/
  tags:
    - test_new_runner
  only:
    - ned_runner #Затычка бранча чтобы ранер не запускался
#    - develop

test-master:
  extends: test
  stage: test
  variables:
    allow_failure: "false"
    ENV: prod
  tags:
    - test_new_runner
  only:
    - main


test-dev:
  extends: test
  stage: test
  variables:
    allow_failure: "false"
    ENV: dev
  tags:
    - test_new_runner
  only:
#    - develop
    - ned_runner


deploy:
  script:
    - php artisan migrate
    - php artisan optimize:clear
    - cp -r $CI_PROJECT_DIR $docker_html_path/$deploy_subfolder
    - cp -Pv $docker_html_path/$deploy_subfolder $docker_html_path/$eploy_subfolder/${ENV}_$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - ls -lha
  artifacts:
    when: always
    name: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
    untracked: true
    paths:
      - tests/js/screenshots/
      - tests/js/screens/
      - tests/js/report/
  cache:
    paths:
      - tests/js/screenshots/
      - tests/js/screens/
      - tests/js/report/
      - storage/
      - public
      - css/
      - img/
  tags:
    - test_new_runner
#  only:
#    - ned_runner #Затычка бранча чтобы ранер не запускался
##    - develop


deploy-dev:
  extends: deploy
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    ENV: dev
    allow_failure: "true"
    deploy_subfolder: "hype-dev"
  only:
#    - develop
    - ned_runner


deploy_master:
  extends: deploy
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    ENV: prod
    allow_failure: "false"
    deploy_subfolder: "hype-prod"
  when: manual
  only:
    - main


activate:
  script:
    - ln -fsnv $docker_html_path/$deploy_subfolder/$ENV_$CI_COMMIT_SHA $docker_html_path/$deploy_subfolder


activate_staging:
  extends: activate
  stage: activate
  variables:
    deploy_subfolder: 'hype-dev'
    ENV: staging
  when: always
  only:
#    - develop
    - ned_runner
#    - /feature-.*/


activate_prod:
  extends: activate
  stage: activate
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  only:
    - main


revert:
  stage: revert
  when: manual
  script:
    - cp -Pv --remove-destination $docker_html_path/$CI_COMMIT_SHA/prev-version $docker_html_path/html
```

Я ожидал, что если я не укажу stage в job'e то она не будет запускаться так как ее ничего не будет трегирить, и разделил job's на 3 типа: для dev, prod, без stage

Что я получил:
Все job's типа без stage залетели в stage test

[image: Все job's типа без stage залетели в stage test]

Так же, предыдущая версия моего gitlab-ci.yml включала в себя stage во всех job's кроме тех в которых написал extends, но тогда gitlab прогонял job + dev_jobs\prod_jobs

[image: job + dev_job\prod_job]

Что мне дописать в job's чтобы запускались только env_jobs где env это dev\prod
[image: Что я хочу получить где env это dev\prod]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ кроется в тех [литературе](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages):

```
Additional details:

If a job does not specify a `stage`, the job is assigned the `test` stage.
```